# What are all the ways to prevent MacBook Pro (mid-2020 model) with Monterey (12.0.1) from using Integrated Graphics Card on boot?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

I know of one unreliable and two reliable ways to get the MacBook Pro (mid-2020, MacBookPro16,1) to use the integrated graphics card (Intel UHD Graphics 630) instead of the discrete graphics card (AMD Radeon Pro 5500M) on boot and am wondering if there are other ways to do so on Monterey.

Unreliable way: keep restarting until boot decides to use integrated graphics card.

Reliable ways:

1. Ensure low battery (unplug from power source) upon boot.
2. Ensure laptop is warm or hot to the touch (unplug from power source) upon boot.

Note: I suspect that the unreliable way is just a special case of the reliable way #2 since restarting the machine multiple time tends to heat it up in the absence of an external cooler that would counteract any heat buildup across restarts.

Also, I've read the other threads mentioning NVRAM changes, disabling system integrity check, and broken links to Apple support pages, but it appears those are all for prior versions of MacBooks/OSX, and I'm interested in MacBook Pro mid-2020 with Monterey (12.0.1).

Additional note: in case anyone is wondering why someone would do this, consider this: one buys an expensive MacBook Pro without AppleCare (was not aware of it at the time of purchase, due to their own ignorance); then within a few months a water accident damages the MBP. Left with no apparent recourse, they pay for a very expensive repair to replace the logic board. Everything works fine until 6 months later the screen goes pixelated and the MBP cannot boot up. Apple store says they would have to send it in, likely resulting in another costly logic board repair; so the person would rather live with restarting the machine in just the right way to avoid further incurring such repair costs.

Comment: If the replacement logic board is at fault, then you should be entitled to get it fixed at no cost. It's worth getting checked out, at least.

Comment: Water spills should be covered in your regular household insurance.

Comment: @benwiggy even though it's been a little over the 90-day warranty period, the nearby Apple store made an exception and sent it in for repair. Thanks.

Comment: @Tetsujin wow, I did not know that. I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @Tetsujin it appears that water spill on computer requires a special computer provision that some insurance policies may not cover unless specifically added

Comment: hmm… yeah. Always check what you're buying ;)) Caveat emptor.